# TYPO3 displays "login incorrect" when trying to view the frontend

Tags: typo3

I want to work local on an pretty old TYPO3 website - Version 4.2.2

So i made a copy of the complete site via FTP, dumped the database and installed a decade old XAMPP Version.

After setting up everything local, inserting the db, configure the install tool, i wanted to view the frontend page but only get a "login incorrect" message. I can login to the backend with no problem, view the page-tree, add or remove users etc, but i can't view the frontend. I only get a "login incorrect" message all the time.

I already set the be and fe loginSecurityLevel to normal, my cookieDomain is blank, cache is cleared, temp is deleted, a new user is created, etc but I can't figure out whats the problem here.

Some help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the error message from TYPO3 or htaccess or ...?

By default there is no FE login in TYPO3, so you should look for a configuration of a neccessary login like access restricted pages, with inheritance.

and so you said you use old software: do these software versions match each other?

Comment: The error message looks like its from TYPO3. When i open the frontend via localhost/mysite/ there shows up a blank page with the letters "login incorrect". Even when i'm in the backend and want to view the page, there just comes up a blank page with "login incorrect" in the body. The online version of the site using php 5.2.17 an mysql 5.6.19, i'm on php 5.2.2 and mysql 5.0.41. Any hints on where i could look up a configuration of accessing restricted pages?

Comment: you can inspect (e.g. web developer kit in FF) whether cookies are set. but the questions stays: what kind of login is requested? and where does the message come from? where is the page configuration? you might enable full display of php-errors (according developer mode in current TYPO3 versions)

Comment: [Thu Nov 23 15:25:29 2017] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] http://localhost/mysite/ - cms: Locking [simple::c70e10e13c915489357fe74ac38ffec9]: Acquired lock

is the error message. Cookies are set.

Comment: are your permissions to filesystem and database correct? and also keep in mind: for 4.2 configuration (localconf.php) is cached in `typo3conf/`

Comment: Permissions are correct, cached localconfig was deleted. Any possibilities to disable the acquired lock?

Comment: you can try the configuration in the Install-Tool. look for "lock" at all configuration. I don't remember what options were availabe with 4.2.

Comment: normaly access restrictions are stored in the pages records. this could be in the top most record and inherited to subpages. an indication would be a different icon in the page tree. But as there is no page content at all I assume a condition in the typoscript testing for live/test platform and blocking access for any other server than live.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help my friend, you guided me into the right direction :-) After four days of further investigation i found the problem.. The connection to the database in \fileadmin\scripts\inc\ known as database.inc.php was misconfigured - hope this will help somebody else searching for the "login incorrect" error :D

Comment: that sound like a very queer installation, as any database access should use core functions, which handles database authorisation. Or you have a login not based on the TYPO3 default tables, which needs mention to give the correct help.

Comment: Anyway: for an update to a current version of TYPO3 you need to change your PHP script from `fileadmin/` to a class in an extension. You might consider an auth-service.